# Variable Dates in Scheduled Bigquery Table Name

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, visualization, analytics

[image]

I have the following requirement as per the screenshot attached.

I need a Dynamic date in the FROM table name in a scheduled Query so each day it will populate yesterdays data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use sharded tables anymore, so I'm not sure if this is the most up to date solution.
Some time ago you could do this way:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT('select count(1) from `', "xxscore-prod.analytics_229726387.events_20201114", '`');
```

This way you can freely construct the table's suffix and replace the date as you wish